# Quotient group of the free group on the alphabet of a string.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, formal-languages, free-groups

For instance, let $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$, and consider $F = F(\Sigma)$, the free group.

Let $s$ be a string, say $s = ab$ and consider the subgroup $H \leqslant F$, $H = \langle t: t \nleqslant s\rangle$ where $\leqslant$ on strings indicates "is a substring of".  Then is $H$ normal?

Let $h \in H$, ie $h \nleqslant s$, and let $f \in F$.  Then $fhf^{-1}$ is certainly in $H$ as you can't form a substring via concatenation if it involves any non substring, so $fhf^{-1} \in \{t \nleqslant s\}$ is in the generating set of $H$ so is in $H$.  Therefore $F/H$ is a group.

What does $F/H$ look like!?  It must be $\{\epsilon, a,b, ab\} \approx \Bbb{Z}_4$ right?

Does this group have a name in literature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subgroup $H$ is all of $F$.  For instance, if $s=ab$, then $aba$ and $abab$ are both in $H$, and hence so is $b=(aba)^{-1}(abab)$.  Similarly, $a\in H$ as well.  You can easily construct similar examples for any value of $s$.

Answer (score 1):

If you pick $s = ab$ as your string, $h = b^{-1}ab$, as your not substring and $f=b$ as your other string, then
$$fhf^{-1} = bb^{-1}abb^{-1} = a \leq ab = s.$$

Comment: Yeah, I saw that happening.  I wonder if it's *ever* normal.

Comment: @FruitfulApproach Now that I think about it, subgroups share the parent's identity, so "", the empty string should be in $H$, but I think the empty string should also be a substring of every string... If so, then H isn't even a subgroup, because the identity isn't in it. :/ The topic seems interesting enough, though!

Comment: It's called you "artificialy add it in", as it's trivial enough to do.  *Actually, $\epsilon \in H$ automatically, by definition of generated subgroup.*

Comment: I'm making an answer.  I think $s = ababab$ might shed some light

Comment: Eh, I somehow missed the $ \langle $, and its pair, don't ask me how ... And sure thing. :)

Comment: You're right though, if $\langle \cdot \rangle$ meant generate as a semigroup.